# Copying and filtering Ruby arrays

Tags: beginner, ruby, array, comparative-review

I'm doing a Ruby exercise to create new arrays with a given filter.

> Copy the values less than 4 in the array stored in the `source` variable
>   into the array in the `destination` variable.

The editorial solution code is:

```
def array_copy(source)
  destination = []
  for number in source
    # Add number to destination if number
    # is less than 4
    destination << number if number < 4
  end
  return destination
end
```

But, as a beginner, I came up with this solution:

```
def array_copy(source)
  return source.select {|i| i < 4}
end
```

Is there any problems with my solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your answer is perfectly valid and much better than the editorial solution.

I only have two suggestions to improve it further:

- variable name `i` is commonly used for array indexes. Using it instead for array values can confuse the reader of the code.
- `return` is not needed - Ruby functions will implicitly return the value of the last evaluated expression.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you have any problems, but you can improve it:

1. In Ruby, you don't need to `return` explicitly:

   ```
   def array_copy(source)
     source.select {|i| i < 4}
   end
   ```
2. The exercise says *copy the values*, so you might prefer using [`select!`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-select-21):

   ```
   def array_copy(source)
     source.select! {|i| i < 4}
   end
   ```

Comment: As `select!` modifies the array in-place, it's actually the opposite of copying the values.

Comment: I understood it as replacing the current values rather than creating a new duplicate. That’s why recommended bang version. 